# Google Maps Api v.3 squares fill color

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps Api v.3. I am able to set colors of all elements except squares (e.g. **Trafargal Square in London**).
I tried all available elements in Google Maps Api Wizzard:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html
but none of them seems to affect squares. They are always gray.

[See print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR9Ub.png)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Which ones did you try?  Which one was closest to what you wanted? And what was wrong with the closest one?

Comment: Please take two minutes to read through the tour at http://stackoverflow.com/tour so you understand what StackOverflow is about and have an idea of how to ask a question. This question isn't to good as it's not clear on what you have done so there is no starting point. When you do the whole tour, you do get a badge as a reward and it will make your experience here so much better.

Comment: I tried all options: administrative.geometry.fill, landscape.man_made.all, poi.geometry.fill, road.geometry.fill etc. None of them is closest, it simpy doesn't work. All elements can be painted except square. I just want to change fill color of square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Map's styles is where the "squares" colour is set. (Assuming by your discussion you mean the base background of your map). The important thing to keep in mind, the styles are applied in the order you code them. So you set the base first. Then you start layering on the other styles.

In the following example, the base is set to a hue of #d400ff (pale purple). Then landscape.man_made is set to #00c3ff with the gamma adjusted so creates a pale blue. Then other objects are styled.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Styling the base map example</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #eee;
      }
      .heading {
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 16px;
         color: #800000;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.810861, 138.728223),
          zoom: 14,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        map.set('styles',[
          {
            "stylers": [
              { "hue": "#d400ff" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [
              { "hue": "#00c3ff" },
              { "gamma": 0.65 }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "poi.park",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [
              { "hue": "#33ff00" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "poi.school",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [
              { "hue": "#ff6e00" },
              { "gamma": 0.32 }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "road.local",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
              { "hue": "#1900ff" },
              { "gamma": 0.28 }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
              { "color": "#338080" },
              { "weight": 1.9 }
            ]
          }
        ]);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="heading">Styling the base map example</div>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A valuable tool for designing the "theme" of your map where you can try out the different elements arranging them in the right order is http://googlemaps.github.io/js-samples/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! **It works perfectly!** It looks like there is no particular styler for squares so only way to set their color is to use general style.

Comment: Your welcome. Appreciate if you set the answer as accepted. Have a great day :)